# Extract text from between quotations and adding a second word

Tags: regex

I need to extract the text in *Gate* with the quotes excluded and also include null as another word to match.

```
# "gate":"A11","terminal":"5"
# "gate":508B,"terminal":"2"
# "gate":"D8","terminal":"1"
# "gate":null,"terminal":null

# desired output:
# A11, 508B, D8, null
```

I tried something like this: `"gate":(.*?),"terminal":.*`, but this would include the quotes. Also, I tried to exclude the quotes by trying `"gate":"([^"]*)","terminal":.*`, but I didn't know to match on "null".

Can someone help with this?

Comment: With PCRE, you can use `"gate":(?|"([^"]*)"|(\w+)),"terminal":.*`

Comment: If your data is all structured like this then I would argue regex is not the right tool for the job.  However, your second option is close. It shouldn't match null. Use `+` instead of `*` to ensure there's something in the quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you what you want, at least for the examples you mentioned:

```
"gate":"?([^"]+|null)"?,"terminal":"?([^"]+|null)"?
```

Note: If the strings can contain escaped quotes, a Regex based solution isn't quite possible.